# Understanding stack trace that is redacted

Tags: ios, stack-trace

I have a stack trace from Flurry that is from a crash that is happening a couple times on my app and I dont understand what is going wrong. Any suggestions or hints how I can make sense of this?

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x184bc2084 <redacted> + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x1951a00e4 _objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                      0x184ab6ff8 <redacted> + 0
3   My     App                          0x100015ef4 __mh_execute_header + 73460
4   My     App                          0x10000c61c __mh_execute_header + 34332
5   My     App                          0x10000b024 __mh_execute_header + 28708
6   CFNetwork                           0x1846624cc <redacted> + 80
7   CFNetwork                           0x18466245c <redacted> + 208
8   CFNetwork                           0x1846625d8 <redacted> + 60
9   CFNetwork                           0x184537684 <redacted> + 104
10  CFNetwork                           0x1845ffcb8 <redacted> + 104
11  CFNetwork                           0x1845239cc <redacted> + 76
12  CoreFoundation                      0x184aa506c _CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
13  CFNetwork                           0x184523878 <redacted> + 136
14  CFNetwork                           0x18452372c <redacted> + 312
15  CFNetwork                           0x184523558 <redacted> + 68
16  CoreFoundation                      0x184b7a324 <redacted> + 24
17  CoreFoundation                      0x184b795c8 <redacted> + 264
18  CoreFoundation                      0x184b77678 <redacted> + 712
19  CoreFoundation                      0x184aa5664 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
20  GraphicsServices                    0x18dbe75a4 _GSEventRunModal + 168
21  UIKit                               0x1893aa4f8 _UIApplicationMain + 1488
22  My     App                          0x10000c8f0 __mh_execute_header + 35056
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x19580ea08 <redacted> + 4
```

Comment: `<redacted>` are shown for some system symbols when symbolicating on device, which is expected to happen. `__mh_execute_header` can also happen when symbolicating app frames on the device. You should get the full crash report and symbolicate it yourself to get proper data.

Comment: @Kerni How do I get the full crash report? I logged into itunes connect and when I go to crash reports I get: `Too few reports have been submitted for a report to be shown.`

Comment: If Flurry doesn't provide the full crash report, you are out of luck.